# Find an array for hasMany relationship

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have relations like this:

- Project has multiple Properties
- Property has multiple Rates

On the project page, I want to display:

- The project, its properties and its latest rate

So far, I have this:

```
$this->set('rates', $this->Rate->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Property.project_id' => $id),
    'fields' => array('Rate.id', 'Rate.rate', 'Rate.floor_rise', 'Property.id'),
    'order' => array('Rate.created DESC')
)));
```

This gives all rates for the respective property, but I only want the latest rate.

How should I do this query?

Comment: It may be worth setting up "containable" if you want your results in one neat array, vs doing this->find for a property, then for the rates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->set('rates', $this->Rate->find('first', array(
'conditions' => array('Property.project_id' => $id),
'fields' => array('Rate.id', 'Rate.rate', 'Rate.floor_rise', 'Property.id'),
'order' => array('Rate.created DESC')
```

)));

Answer (score 3):

Change `'all'` to `'first'` in your find, and as you already have a good `'order'` you should be fine.

Comment: or either add `'limit'=>1` to your existing code. However @ianmjones response is more 'cake-way'